# Pyside/PyQt: 'Global' widget?

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, pyside

I am making a simple plotting application in PySide.

The main window has a `chart` widget which contains my plot `figure`.

There are various other widgets and dialogs which need to access the `chart` widget to alter properties of the `figure` (appearance, plot data etc...).

At the moment, my widgets require the instance of `chart` to be passed into them when initialised...this is a terrible way of allowing everything to talk to `chart` as there are chains of this reference being passed around.

Is there a way to make the `chart` widget 'global' /accessible from any widget?

I have thought about creating a singleton of `chart` outside of the main window - any reasons why this would be a bad idea?

Comment: How about putting everything inside a class, and making `chart` a member of this class?

Comment: how does that help? `chart` itself is a class, inherited from matplotlib's FigureCanvas which is a subclass of QWidget I believe. 
`chart` is currently instantiated in my `Main` class which is an instance of QMainWindow as that is where the `chart` widget 'resides'

Comment: The idea being that you have methods within this class that act on the other widgets and provide `chart` when required, rather than making it a member of each and every widget. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem, but thoughts of using globals/singletons are often a sign you may need to reconsider the structure of your code. What is the purpose of `chart`? Maybe you could post some code to make your intentions clearer.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is communication by [signals and slots](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide), so the main window has some slots (draw this, draw that, ...) and each of the other widgets has a signal (I want this to be drawn) and then you connect the signals and the slots. This is probably the most decoupled solution and I would prefer it.

You can use a global. No problem with it. [Global variables are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) by itself but if this doesn't bother you, go with it.

Finally the idea of *user3419537* seems like a good thing to do. You can bundle all the widgets that belong together in one class and then access the chart widget as a class member. This is probably better than a global.

Comment: signals and slots may be the way to go.